# What is the right away to multiply a column with serial numbers?

Tags: r

```
structure(list(Time = structure(c(1080827100, 1080827400, 1080827700, 
1080828000, 1080828300, 1080828600, 1080828900, 1080829200, 1080829500, 
1080829800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    precip = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02)), .Names = c("Time", 
"precip"), row.names = 236614:236623, class = "data.frame")
```

I want to add the precip with a sequence of numbers that are odd multiples of 2.5

```
p1*2.5 + p2*7.5+ p3*12.5 +...
```

Where p1,p2,p3 are rows of precip.

How can I generate this sequence of numbers (2.5, 7.5, 12.5, 17.5 etc) based on length of dataframe and add it as additional column in the same dataframe?

I tried: `df$new <-seq(0,nrow(df),2.5)`

This is wrong ofcourse. I need to be able to mention the number of values I want instead of the last value using nrow(df).

Comment: `seq` has a `length.out` argument and a `by` argument that should fit the bill.  You tell it where to start, how many values to generate, and how far to step each time

Comment: If you're going to add a column then it has to have the same length as the others, so what's wrong with using `nrow(df)`?

Comment: Basically, they have to be odd multiples of 2.5. It's a variation of this when time periods are of 5 minutes each. This example is of unequal time periods: https://math.dartmouth.edu/~klbooksite/4.11/411examples/411flow.htm

Comment: The second parameter for seq is for final value, and not length.

Comment: `seq(2.5, length.out = nrow(df), by = 5)`

Comment: @Jota This is what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Please remember to mark a solution as accepted. If Jota wants to move his comment to an answer and you want to accept that one that's more than fine of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
remove <- seq(0,100, 2.5)
nums   <- remove[c(F, T)]
nums   <- nums[1:nrow(df1)]

df1$new <- nums
```

Note if you know the number of elements you want then you can replace `100` with that (or 2x that, actually) and skip the 3rd line. Otherwise `100` is an arbitrary large number.

So a variation would be

```
remove <- seq(0,50, 2.5)
nums   <- remove[c(F, T)]

df1$new <- nums
```

---

or, as mentioned by Jota, you could do

```
 seq(2.5, length.out = nrow(df), by = 5)
```

Comment: @maximusdooku You're welcome. Yes, I included it as part of my answer. Please remember to mark a solution as accepted. If Jota wants to move his comment to an answer and you want to accept that one that's fine of course.